# Angular js PivotTable Chart (written by nicolas) : Can we reduce the width of table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pivot-table

Currently the pivotTable takes an autoWidth. I want to reduce its width without making changes in the library.
is it possible?

Comment: show your code what have you tried already

Comment: Check this URL 
http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/c3.html

Comment: I want to reduce the width of overall pivot Grid chart.